# components does not scale properly

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

For my WPF project in C#, I have to create a menu state which should look like image below

[image]

So far, I have created

[image]

XAML Code for this window:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="125"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="400*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- title -->
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Heavy">
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock>Title</TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
        </Label>
        <!-- menu -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>                
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium">
                <Viewbox><TextBlock>State</TextBlock></Viewbox>
            </Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium">
                <Viewbox><TextBlock>State</TextBlock></Viewbox>
            </Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium">
                <Viewbox><TextBlock>State</TextBlock></Viewbox>
            </Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium">
                <Viewbox><TextBlock>State</TextBlock></Viewbox>
            </Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium">
                <Viewbox><TextBlock>State</TextBlock></Viewbox>
            </Button>            
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Problem with this window is this components (label and buttons with their contents) does not scale properly. What I want is, when I resize the window I want this components to be proportional to window. Not sure if the grid layout is problem, but how can I fix this components scale properly.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I followed your instructions and I like the results (everything seems to scale good enough),

[image]

but I have **two** more **minor problems**:

1) With a new changes to XAML code, my last button is colliding with the south border of the window, which is not what I want. What I want is an empty space with size of almost exactly (if possible) or close space, like between Label "Title" and north border of the window.
I found solution by defining a new line at the end `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>`. Not sure if this is a correct way to go.

2) Thus, so far I understand that *, 1*, 2*,... multiplies the current size. However, it seems I still feel like I don't fully understand it. Currently, I am asking myself, how can I now change the  size (width or height in some case) of the button components inside grid layout? 
Finally, do I change properties for the size directly to button or via grid layout?

Here is the code for a new window.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TypeRacer_Client.state.MenuState"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/> 
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- title -->
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Heavy">
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock>Title</TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
        </Label>
        <!-- menu -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>                
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium">
                <Viewbox><TextBlock>State</TextBlock></Viewbox>
            </Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium">
                <Viewbox><TextBlock>State</TextBlock></Viewbox>
            </Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium">
                <Viewbox><TextBlock>State</TextBlock></Viewbox>
            </Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium">
                <Viewbox><TextBlock>State</TextBlock></Viewbox>
            </Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium">
                <Viewbox><TextBlock>State</TextBlock></Viewbox>
            </Button>            
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: in what way is it not scaling properly? P.S. you could use column widths of *, 2*, and * with the same result as 200*, 400*, 200*

Comment: But how can it scale.  You gave the rows fixed heights.

Comment: Hey, I edit my post. Please read. Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use star sizing (ratios) to size your grid's rows etc.  Like *, 2*, 4* etc.  This will make the rows and columns keep the same ratios, no matter what size the window is, like this:

```
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
<RowDefinition Height="2* />  //this will be 2x the previous row's height
```

Style the buttons for consistent width/height/other properties etc.

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="SomeButtonStyle">
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="90" /> 
 </Style>
```

then , for each button you want the same height/width/whatever property:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource SomeButtonStyle}" />
```

This will keep you from putting a width, height or font etc. in EVERY button you made, and makes it much faster to change the value in one place, instead of every button.

Comment: You can let the buttons fill the grid's rows/columns, or you can explicitly set a size for the buttons, either way.  if you are setting the button's size, you can make a Style for the buttons and apply that style to each button, that way you don't have to change EACH button if you want to make them bigger/smaller etc. I added a small example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you on the reply! Could you please give an example of what u mean when it comes about to change the size of the buttons? That's all.

Comment: Using ViewBox is probably complicating your sizing etc, because i believe that makes everything fill the space.  Not sure why I'd ever use that...

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm new to WPF so I don't know anything about Style. I will try "<Style>" out soon or later. Bye.

Comment: Well, before this, I was searching for examples, on how to scale font size. Because, with out it, it had fixed font size of 12px. They recommended ViewBox. So, what is the way to go when it comes to scale font size ?